# Database design Composite Key dilemma

Tags: database, erd

When designing a table for a many to many relations ship [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqMdf.jpg) sides primary key will come to the [M] side the middle table, my current middle table is

```
Salesline : Itemid(PK), SOId(PK), userid(PK)
```

or

```
Salesline : Itemid(PK), SOId(PK), 
userid_salesorder(PK) , // links to the salesorder.userid attribute 
userid_item(PK) // links to the item.userid attribute
```

Which is the correct way ?

[image: ERD]

Comment: Why would you want a separate relationship between SalesLine and User?

Comment: user-salesorder -> 1 user can create many sales orders, user - items - > 1 user can create many items

but the middle table is not about who created its about combination of primary keys, by the way I have no idea why I wanna separate salesline and user !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the natural realtionships between your entities are:

- A User can place 0, 1 or more SalesOrders
- A SalesOrder may include 1 or more SalesLines
- A SalesLine corresponds to exactly 1 Item
- An Item can be ordered on many SalesOrders

I would recommend to break the realtionship between the User and Item tables and to move the quantity of the particular item ordered to the SalesLine table. User, SalesOrder and Item should have simple, possibly surrogate, primary key. The primary key of the SalesLine may be composite, consisting of the foreign key to the SalesOreder table and, say, a line number within the order.